# Get value of dynamic input element in form object

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My question is: How do I reference a dynamic 'name' of an input element in a form?

For instance, with the following HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="qty1" value="input1" />
     <input type="text" name="qty2" value="input2" />
     <input type="text" name="qty3" value="input3" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="checkVal(this.form); return false;" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkVal(form) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        alert(form.qty+i.value);  // Here's where my problem is..
    }
}
```

The above javascript does not work. The alert is outputting `NaN`.

How do I reference `qty1`, `qty2`, and `qty3` in a for loop using `i` variable?

Here's a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/MRzWf/

Comment: alert(document.getelementbyid('qty' + i).value);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [*Bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
 form["qty" + i].value
```

```js
function checkVal(form) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        console.log("qty" + i, form["qty" + i].value);
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="qty1" value="input1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="qty2" value="input2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="qty3" value="input3" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="checkVal(this.form); return false;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply login as a dictionary

http://jsfiddle.net/MRzWf/2/

```
 alert(form["qty"+i].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `form.qty+i`,

To access the element of array you should used `index` inside the parenthesis.

There is another way to check value of input. Here is one.

```
  function checkVal(form) {
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          if(allInputs[i].type == 'text'){
                alert(allInputs[i].value);  
          }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YNfzx/)

Comment: you never use the arg 'form' can remove that

Answer (score 1):

> Standard Solution

Using: `form.elements[]` should work in all browsers..

```
function checkVal(form) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        alert(form.elements["qty"+i].value);

        /* OR using dynamic name variable
        var ename = "qty"+i;
        alert(form.elements[ename].value);
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for the above problem

```
function checkVal(form) {
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value);
}  }
```