# JavaScript- dynamically adding input to a page

Tags: javascript

i am using JavaScript to add a div on the fly. The div should contain a form input whose 'name' attribute  WILL changes in value incrementally.

I have managed to do this- I however have two problems.

**First Problem:**

The first div that i created is cancelled out by the next dynamically created div.

thus, when i submit  the form, the first dynamically created imput form is blank-
 but subsequent ones have values on them.

**MY CODE :**

**html**

```
<div id="dynamicDivSection"></div>

<button id="addbutton">add box</button>

 <div id="boxes">
   <div class="box">
       <input type="text" id='dynamic-imput' name="">   
   </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var addbutton = document.getElementById("addbutton");
var key = 1; 

addbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  key++;
  document.getElementById('dynamic-imput').name = 'ser['+key+'][\'name\']';

  var boxes = document.getElementById("boxes");
  var head  = document.getElementById("dynamicDivSection");

  var clone = boxes.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  head.appendChild(clone);
});
```

i suspect that the problem is causing by this:

> document.getElementById('dynamic-imput').name =
>   'ser['+key+'][\'name\']';

**i.e** when i create the dynamic div it creates several inputs on the page that contain the same Id. if i am correct, then perhaps teh solution is to change the Id of the newly created imput - however, i am not sure how to change the Id of a dynamically created Imput.

**Second problem.**

i want each dynamically created div to go to the top of the page; i.e to be placed before the earlier created dynamic div- however, at the moment each dynamically created div go directly under the first dynamically created div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of dynamic input element in form object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787104/get-value-of-dynamic-input-element-in-form-object)

Comment: hi Hitmands- its not a duplicate. please look at the problem i have. its totally different from the page you showed

Comment: it is the same... You have to work with dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert as the first child with:

```
parent.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', nodeToInsert);
```

You can get and set attributes such as `id` with [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute). Though I'm not sure why you even need an ID here, it would be simpler not to have one and select the element with a class.

```js
var addbutton = document.getElementById("addbutton");
var key = 1; 

addbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  key++;
  document.getElementById('dynamic-imput').name = 'ser['+key+'][\'name\']';

  var boxes = document.getElementById("boxes");
  var head  = document.getElementById("dynamicDivSection");

  var clone = boxes.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  var clonedInput = clone.firstElementChild;
  clonedInput.setAttribute('id', clonedInput.getAttribute('id') + '-' + head.children.length);

  head.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', clone);
});
```

```html
<div id="dynamicDivSection"></div>

<button id="addbutton">add box</button>

 <div id="boxes">
   <div class="box">
       <input type="text" id='dynamic-imput' name="">   
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Dominic- but what about when you have other elements within the form. for example, i also want to place a textarea- i tried to do this : var clonetwo = boxes.secondElementChild.cloneNode(true). but it did not work